# Centos 7 on Windows Azure, who mounts /dev/sdb? (systemd)

Tags: linux, azure, systemd, centos7

I need to find out which `systemd` service mounts `/dev/sdb` (aka `/mnt/resource`) on Windows Azure? I am using Centos 7 image and it is systemd-based and I am trying to launch a service that depends on `/mnt/resource` mounted already.

Tried googling but not much luck yet.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find an answer after a while. It is not that simple though:

- The service that mounts `/mnt/resource` is called `waagent.service`
- However, `systemd` only allows you to wait till it starts, not till it finishes startup
- Therefore, it my script I used the following detection code:

```
LINES=`df | grep /mnt/resource | wc -l`
while [ $LINES -lt 1 ]
do
        sleep 1
        LINES=`df | grep /mnt/resource | wc -l`
done
```